# get recommended posts from own profile through api

Tags: medium.com-publishing-api

Using the Medium API, is it possible to get all of the posts I have recommended (or clapped)?

Within my Medium profile, I can see the posts I have clapped (see image below). I wish to retrieve these through the API.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is possible with the API, but you can do this using the RSS feeds. Here's the recommendations from my own Medium page:

```
https://medium.com/feed/@jamesjefferyuk/has-recommended
```

Replace the username with your own.

Answer (score 0):

Based off Medium's [API docs](https://github.com/Medium/medium-api-docs), there does not seem to be a forward facing endpoint to get your recommended posts. You could try to [scrape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping) your recommendations page, though I don't know if Medium's [Terms of Service](https://medium.com/policy/medium-terms-of-service-9db0094a1e0f) allow scraping, so if you're going to go that route, read through their terms to make sure you won't be putting your account in danger of getting banned, shutdown, etc.